# Password protect EVERY directory with Apache

Tags: apache

Is there a way to password protect every directory requested in Apache?  So that regardless what location the request is for, it must be authenticated.  Also, can this be done WITHOUT .htaccess, but just in a conf file somewhere?

Comment: You can put a conf file anywhere you want as long as it's called from main server configuration. What have you tried so far and why didn't it fulfil your purpose?

Comment: Whenever I try to add Auth directives outside of a directory enclosure, I get an apache error on restart: "AuthUserFile not allowed here".  So while I can put a conf file anywhere, it still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this finally:

```
<DirectoryMatch ".">
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "Protected Realm"
    AuthType Basic

    require valid-user
</DirectoryMatch>
```